Why do we say that Jesus shed blood to the last drop on the Cross?
We read in Jn 19:33-34( KJV):

But when they came to Jesus, and saw that he was dead already, they brake not his legs: But one of the soldiers with a spear pierced his side, and forthwith came there out blood and water.

Possible physiological reasons for the flow of  blood and water include the phenomenon where  the physical toll of the crucifixion and scourging  caused a buildup of fluid around Jesus' heart and lungs.
Going back to OT, we see in  Lev 5:9:

And he shall sprinkle of the blood of the sin offering upon the side of the altar; and the rest of the blood shall be wrung out at the bottom of the altar: it is a sin offering.

Traditionally, the water from Jesus' pierced heart is taken as an indication that he had no blood left in the body . (A number of prayers contain the statement that Jesus shed blood to the last drop in order to atone for the sins of mankind ). In fact, John the Evangelist's narration appears to have been made with the purpose of substantiating that Jesus in deed was dead on the cross. Traditional teachings perhaps put together both the Leviticus instructions on draining of the sacrificial animal/ bird of all its blood, as well as Jn 19:34 to conclude that Jesus had shed blood to the last drop on the cross.
My question is: How do Bible scholars interpret Jn 19:34 ? Inputs from experts of any denomination are welcome.

"Why do we say that Jesus shed blood to the last drop on the Cross?" Who says that? I've never heard it before!

Thanks, curiousdannii. Introduction to the Vth prayer of Sorrowful Mysteries of the Holy Rosary is an example. I am not sure if the text is approved for use across all Catholic families .

There is only one record in scripture of blood shed by Jesus. It is John's testimony of what he witnessed at Golgotha. There is no indication of how much was shed, only that the word 'shed' (in the original) indicates copious shedding.

That sounds strange, Nigel J ! If Jesus shed blood after his death, what did he die of ? Even Pilate was surprised to hear that Jesus had died so soon, presumably because convicts were reported to have remained on the cross for days on end. Mind that Pilate had wanted to let Jesus go after the flogging, which means Jesus underwent double conviction . Could there be Roman flogging without bloodshed ? And did the nails and the crown of thorns not cause continuous bleeding ?

The nails, thorns, and wounds from the scourging presumably all caused some blood loss (though it's not explicitly stated), but probably not significant. Crucifixion victims could survive for days and blood loss wasn't a primary cause of death. I have to agree with the other commentators that I've never heard this claim and don't really see a justification for it in Scripture.

Jim Caviezel who enacted Jesus in the film Passion of Christ had a heavy rubber board strapped to his back while the flogging scene was being shot. One ' soldier' missed to flogs which hit Jim on real flesh . He couldn't help abusing the soldier , forgetting for a moment that he was enacting Jesus.  Jim says it felt like the whip was piercing right into his heart ! By Jewish standards, Jesus was whipped 39 times. Who knows how many, by Roman standards !

I won’t repeat the other points that have been made. Two interesting point you raise 1) 'Jesus shed blood after his death'  - that would be an interesting Q, not sure if you can shed blood after your death - nor would water and blood gush out.  2) John witnessed - Mark 14:50 Then everyone deserted Him and fled.

@anothertheory The lance pierced upwards through the pericardium (fluid-filled sac containing the large blood vessels) into the blood-filled chambers of the heart. These (vessels and chambers) would be full of blood under pressure. after the muscle of the heart stopped pumping. Thus blood (from vessels and chambers) and water (from the pericardium) flowed freely by gravity from the still upright body on the cross. This signifies, beyond a peradventure, that death had occurred.

@NigelJ once dead the heart stops pumping so cannot gush out,  'lance pierced upwards'  based on what?  yes the blood moves due to gravity - if hung would move to the leg’s / feet, not side of the body.  Cuts etc... are used to stop the blood clotting.  2) everyone fled so how do they know / who told them?

It looks like a childish argument to say that no disciple was present at the crucifixion. True, they fled at the arrest of Jesus, but once Jesus alone was put on trial and convicted, one of them namely, John came back . Peter too was outside the court watching what was happening to the Master of course feigning total detachment .

All of this debate and 2 downvotes, the question seems okay, just lacking a clear source for understanding. Clearly it is a denomination or lesser practice that people do not recognize. Why are we debating things in the comments people??  Kadalikatt can you please clarify the source in the original question and make it possible for someone to answer?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - I’m going by text - happy for you to show be the passages that you rely on - watching the court hearing is different and he also then fled.  You rely need to provided sources for your opinions, a film not really a good source

@anothertheory There was specifically 1 disciple present at the crucifixion.  (John 19:26-27) who went with Christ's Mother up to the cross.

@anothertheory "'lance pierced upwards' based on what?" - The answer to that should be obvious by picturing the scene. The soldier on the ground, Christ on the cross above him. Depending on how high the cross was, perhaps the soldier could have stabbed horizontally by raising the spear above his head, but if the crossbar was from 3 to 4 meters off the ground (which was normal), that seems somewhere between very unnatural and actually impossible. As for witnesses, John was present as noted by Wyrsa, also several women, and possibly others. John came back, others could have too.

@user111403 yes noted - yes cross 3-4m above ground (spear / pilum about 2m) upwards motion, but unlikely to reach the 'heart' & my initial point heart not pumping, no gush.  Yes it implies John was there but Mark clearly says they all fled, but yes could have come back.  Just a couple of points I found interesting.

What if the soldier was mounted on horse ? He could have held the lance by the head and inserted it point blank into the heart of Jesus !

@KadalikattJosephSibichan possibly horse about 1.5m but it doesn’t mention & says 'side' note heart - an argument can be had that the cut would help stop the blood from clotting and get blood flowing int eh body again - but we have to go with the evidence not what could have or might have happened.

If the piercing was done through the side, Jesus' rib would have to be broken. But that was not to be the case ! If the lance pierced below the ribs, his intestine would have come out with the lance tip !

The hasta was a spear used by early Roman legionaries that was about 2.4 meters (8 feet) long. The hasta was used for thrusting, unlike the pilum, verutum, and lancea, which were thrown.

I am unaware of any such reference... though it is poetic. In hindsight bleeding internally would also explain why Christ died before multiple days of suffering, etc...

Regarding the Blood and water however I point out that your reason given is flawed.

Traditionally, the water from Jesus' pierced heart is taken as an indication that he had no blood left in the body.

I'm not aware of this traditional perspective, a source for it would be interesting. People in ancient times were not unintelligent, and the gospels reflect careful attention to detail.
I see in the comments much medical lack of knowledge.
For the consideration of all...
The medical explanation: That it was haemothorax (from all the lashes and beating), that is when you bleed internally into a space within your chest. As He was still in death, and had been just hanging there for some time (unlike in film interpretations) it is a very common thing for this blood to separate into red cells and plasma. (Picture found on Aleteia.org)

The guards mocked and beat him, hitting him while blindfolded (they didn't lightly slap him did they?)

Luke 22:63-65:  Now the men who held Jesus mocked Him and beat Him. And having blindfolded Him, they struck Him on the face and asked Him, saying, “Prophesy! Who is the one who struck You?” And many other things they blasphemously spoke against Him.
Luke 23:1 Then the whole multitude of them arose and led Him to Pilate.
Luke 23:7+11 And as soon as he knew that He belonged to Herod’s jurisdiction, he sent Him to Herod, who was also in Jerusalem at that time....Then Herod, with his men of war, treated Him with contempt and mocked Him, arrayed Him in a gorgeous robe, and sent Him back to Pilate.

How do Romans flog? (Differently from how Jews do!)
They use a whip called a "Flagrum", think of a whip with multiple lashes each tipped with metal or bone.


Isaiah 52:14: Just as many were astonished at you, So His visage was marred more than any man, And His form more than the sons of men;

The Passion of Christ movie has it's issues... but think of the back of Christ with more muscle than skin showing... add in getting "shoved around, pushed to the ground repeatedly, kicked, spat on, "slapped", etc...

The Theological perspective: Well Blood and Water are the sacraments of baptism and eucharist. Baptism brings us into the life of the Church and the Eucharist sustains us in our faith.

St. John Chrysostom: The blood and water that flowed from Christ’s side on the cross were symbols of the eucharist and baptism, prefigured by the blood of the Passover Lamb. (Crossroads Initiative Website)

